# Consider defining a bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm new about spring and my purpose is crea two object and one object print a string and the second object ( that has dipendency with first object take the value e prints an output). It is an exercise:

Helloworld.java is this:

```
@Component
public class HelloWorld {
    
    private String message="";  


    public void setMessage(String message) {
        
        this.message = message;
        
    }


    @Bean
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

Person class does this:

```
@Component
public class Person {
    
    private String person="Jessy";
    
    public void setPerson(String person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
    
// I want receive hellowordbean and I want print the first message and join the two message
    @Autowired
    public String printMessage(HelloWorld message) {
        return message.getMessage()+" - "+this.person;
    }

}
```

this is main class:

```
@ComponentScan(value={"com.example.bean"})

public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(HelloWorld.class, args);
        HelloWorld word=context.getBean(HelloWorld.class);
        
        word.setMessage("hi world");
        
        ApplicationContext personContext = SpringApplication.run(Person.class, args);
        Person person=personContext.getBean(Person.class);
        person.setPerson("Jimbey");
        System.out.println(person.printMessage(word));
    }

}
```

I play run and I obtain

> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of method printMessage in com.example.bean.Person required
> a bean of type 'com.example.bean.HelloWorld' that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.bean.HelloWorld' in your
> configur

I don't know how resolve this problem, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong :( I recommend you read a tutorial about how to build a hello world app with Spring.

1. Remove `@Autowired` annotation from `printMessage` method in `Person` class. Here you can see how to use `@Autowired` annotation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire.
2. Use `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on `TestApplication` class. It creates all beans annotated with `@Component` annotation.